# Issue with header files in OpenCV 2.4.3 on FreeBSD

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, freebsd

I'm currently working on a study comparing the performance of different operating systems in image processing.
Because of this, i have to install OpenCV 2.4.x (2.4.3 preferably) on a FreeBSD system.

The problem is that it includes asm/types.h, which is not a POSIX-compliant library but rather a Linux one.

So i run cmake with the standard flags suggested by the install guide:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

Where .. points correctly to the source folder. Everything goes ok, so i run make:

> [ 16%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_libv4l.cpp.o 
>   /root/work/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_libv4l.cpp:238:54: error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory

The question is: what should i do in order to tell the compiler that it needs to include another header instead of the original header file?

Comment: you can respond or accept as answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was addressed at [Bug#651872: opencv: FTBFS on kfreebsd](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-651872-opencv-ftbfs-kfreebsd-help-205753341.html)

In **modules/highgui/src/cap_libv4l.cpp**, ***remove or comment out*** the following include:

```
#include <asm/types.h>
```

Do the same in **modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp**.